# C# Entity Framework Code-First- How do you add a row with foreign key using just the id of that foreign key?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

If I have the following classes (using CodeFirst Entity Framework):

```
public class Notifications
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual ClientDetails Client { get; set; }
    public virtual NotificationTypes NotificationType { get; set; }
    public virtual NotificationFreqs Frequency { get; set; }
    public virtual NotificationStatus Status { get; set; }
    public DateTime SendDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? SentDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime QueueDate { get; set; }
}

public class NotificationFreqs
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(25)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class NotificationStatus
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(25)]
    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

When adding a new notification, whats the most efficient way to say `notification.status = 1` ?
Do I have to query the DB each time to get the list available?

```
var notification = new Notifications();

var notificationType = db.NotificationTypes.FirstOrDefault(n => n.ID == notificationTypeId);
var notificationFreq = db.NotificationFreqs.FirstOrDefault(n => n.Name == setting.Value);

notification.NotificationType = notificationType; // Works
notification.Frequency = notificationFreq; // Works
notification.Status = new NotificationStatus { ID = 1 };  // Obviously doesn't work
```

I feel like hitting the DB this many times is inefficient but I do want these values normalized and in the db.

Any suggestions or is the way I'm doing `NotificationType` & `Frequency` the only way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to fix your class. Add Id fields:

```
public class Notifications
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual ClientDetails Client { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("NotificationType")]
    public int? Type_ID  { get; set; }
    public virtual NotificationTypes NotificationType { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Frequency")]
    public int? Frequency_ID { get; set; }
    public virtual NotificationFreqs Frequency { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Status")]
    public int? Status_ID { get; set; }
    public virtual NotificationStatus Status { get; set; }

    public DateTime SendDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? SentDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime QueueDate { get; set; }
}
```

in this case:

```
notification.Type_ID = notificationTypeId; 
notification.Frequency_ID = notificationFreq.ID; 
notification.Status_ID = 1
```

Comment: Would this add another column to the DB?  By using the virtual columns, it's already added a column called Frequency_ID, Status_ID, etc..

Comment: Ah, i should mention i'm doing code-first db.

Comment: In this case you have to use existing columns. I will update my answer.

Comment: Nice!  This did exactly what I needed and after switching them to non-nullable (removed the ?) , it fixed a few things in the foreign key setup as well.  Thank you!